# Out Of Memory Exception in Foreach

Tags: c#, .net, out-of-memory, filestream

I am trying to create a function that will retrieve all the uploaded files (which are now saved as byte in the database) and download it in a single zip file. I currently have 6000 files to download (and the number could grow).

The functionality is already working (from retrieval to download) if I limit the number of files being downloaded, otherwise, I get an `OutOfMemoryException` on the `ForEach` loop.

Here's a pseudo code: *(files variable is a list of byte array and file name)*

```
var files = getAllFilesFromDB(); 
foreach (var file in files) 
{ 
    var tempFilePath = Path.Combine(path, filename);        
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(tempfileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
    {
        stream.Write(file.byteArray, 0, file.byteArray.Length);        
    }
}

private readonly IEntityRepository<File> fileRepository;

IEnumerable<FileModel> getAllFilesFromDb()
{
    return fileRepository.Select(f => new FileModel(){ fileData = f.byteArray, filename = f.fileName});
}
```

My question is, is there any other way to do this to avoid getting such errors?

Comment: first why do you store files in a database? you'll just over charge your db

Comment: Pure guess. You're running out of memory... How big does files get?

Comment: Try compiling x64...

Comment: Please post the `getAllFilesFromDB` method. My guess is that `getAllFilesFromDB` returns `IEnumerable<Something>`, so you have deferred execution until you actually start enumerating.

Comment: If you want help, you're going to have to post a minimal and complete example. Otherwise, all potential answers will be based on speculation and guesswork.

Comment: And now we need to see `fileRepository`...

Comment: Well if you hold the data for more than 6000 Files and all around 4MB, they add up. How much ram you got available? You could try split it up in small chunks (take & skip)

Comment: So when you're saying "it returns a list" you didn't actually mean "it returns a List<T>". Please post a [mcve] instead of all this hypothetical, broken, code (for instance, your method returns a collection of "files", yet you're constructing a "file" for each element, clearly this is just make-believe code).

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Returning a list would likely consume even more memory but it is difficult to say without seeing the underlying store.

Comment: Yes, agreed, but if we're not going to see the exact code, guessing at wrong information isn't going to help anyone.

Comment: @reneeculaway there is not enough information here to make any conclusion aside from what has already been suggested: Insufficient memory to process the workload.

Comment: There is nothing in the code you would post which gives away any IP of your company. You're simply reading data from a database and writing it to disk.

Comment: I understand perfectly but you must also understand that beyond just saying "We understand you have a memory problems and here are some things you can try" we can't really help you. I can say that the problem is most likely related to how your repository retrieves the files.

Comment: You can create a zip file on disk, and add files to it as you go. The [ZipFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx) class will come in handy here.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid this problem, you could avoid loading all the contents of all the files in one go. Most likely you will need to split your database call in to two database calls.

1. Retrieve a list of all the files **without their contents** but with some identifier - like the PK of the table.
2. A method which retrieves the contents of an individual file.

Then your (pseudo)code becomes

```
get list of all files
for each file
    get the file contents
    write the file to disk
```

---

Another possibility is to alter the way your query works currently, so that it uses [deferred execution](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2007/12/10/linq-and-deferred-execution/) - this means it will not actually load all the files at once, but stream them one at a time from the database - but without seeing more code from your repository implementation, I cannot/ will not guess the right solution for you.

Comment: @AluanHaddad yes, but as per the comments I'm not going to guess at the right actual code to do that. This answers the question `is there any other way to do this to avoid getting such errors` whilst avoiding the guesswork.